# How to bind to everything within a frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to bind a double click command, to a frame, but I want the command to bind to everything within the frame, not just the frame itself (want to bind to all child elements of the frame)

Here is how I tried to bind a command to a frame

```py
from tkinter import *


class CustomFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomFrame, self).__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        label = Label(self, text="Click Me", bg="red")
        label.place(width=50, height=50, x=25, y=25)
        self.configure(width=100, height=100)


class window(Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.geometry("200x200")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        frame = CustomFrame(self, bg="green")
        frame.place(x=30, y=30)
        frame.bind('<Double-Button-1>', lambda e: print("testing")) # binding the command here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = window()
    window.mainloop()
```

How would I make it so the "click me" `Label` is bound to the same command, and all child elements too.

Comment: @HenryYik I tried `frame.bind_all()` but that binds the command to the entire window, not just the frame itself.

Comment: Right. I guess you can loop through the child widgets by `winfo_children()` and bind each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HenryYik helped answer my own question with the `.winfo_children()` method

If making a `CustomFrame`, you can make a`.bind_frame()` command of the `Frame` to bind to all children of your `CustomFrame` like this:

```py
class CustomFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomFrame, self).__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        label = Label(self, text="Click Me", bg="red")
        label.place(width=50, height=50, x=25, y=25)
        self.configure(width=100, height=100)

    def bind_frame(self, sequence=None, func=None, add=None):
        self.bind(sequence, func, add)
        for child in self.winfo_children():
            child.bind(sequence, func, add)
```